# why wont python add inside this function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a sorta beginners level enigma machine and I have a problem with the rotors and them not increasing after the first run through with a letter. Down below is the function with said problem

```py
def rotating(rotate_a, rotate_b, rotate_c, add_amount):
    rotate_a += 1
    print("")
    if rotate_a == 27:
        rotate_a = 0
        rotate_b += 1
        add_amount += 1
        rotate_a_b_c(b1, add_amount)
    else:
        rotate_a_b_c(a1, add_amount)
        add_amount += 1
        rotate_a += 1
    if rotate_b == 27:
        rotate_b = 0
        rotate_c += 1
        add_amount += 1
        rotate_a_b_c(c1, add_amount)
    else:
        add_amount += 1
    if rotate_c == 27:
        rotate_c = 0
        add_amount += 1
    else:
        add_amount += 1
    print(rotate_a, rotate_b, rotate_c)
```

The way I want this to work is there is another function encrypting and once it encrypts one letter it will go to move the rotors(add_ammount is a little feature that is not important) at the bottom of the original code you can see what is printing out all the 1 and 0

```
C:\Users\jgola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe "C:/Users/jgola/PycharmProjects/Game/enigma matchine.py"
word to be coded(NO CAPS): abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yz ab cder ghij klmn opqr stuv wxwz

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0

1 0 0
bxtu disw amlj gvqy rcze okfh npbx tudc swam ljgv qyrc zeok fhfp 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

this is the output of the enigma machine(we are focusing on the ones and zeros) every time a new set of numbers are printed it should have an increase in the numbers but it doesn't. why exactly is it doing that and what can I do to fix this?

```
def coding(a, b, c, d):
    add_amount = 0
    roa = 0
    rob = 0
    roc = 0
    final = str()
    var = input("word to be coded(NO CAPS): ")
    var = word_preparing(var)
    var_len = int(len(var) / 4)
    for z in range(0, var_len):
        x = z * 4
        for l in range(0, 4):
            start = ord(var[l+x])-97
            for i in range(0, 26):
                if a[start][1] == b[i][0]:
                    start = i
                    break
            for i in range(0, 26):
                if b[start][1] == c[i][0]:
                    start = i
                    break
            for i in range(0, 26):
                if c[start][1] == d[i][0]:
                    start = i
                    break
            for i in range(0, 26):
                if d[start][1] == c[i][0]:
                    start = i
                    break
            for i in range(0, 26):
                if c[start][1] == b[i][0]:
                    start = i
                    break
            for i in range(0, 26):
                if b[start][1] == a[i][0]:
                    start = i
                    end = chr(a[start][1]+96)
                    final += end
                    rotating(roa, rob, roc, add_amount)
                    a = [(a1[0], 22), (a1[1], 24), (a1[2], 15), (a1[3], 8), (a1[4], 10), (a1[5], 9), (a1[6], 26),
                         (a1[7], 16), (a1[8], 2), (a1[9], 21), (a1[10], 20),
                         (a1[11], 1), (a1[12], 6), (a1[13], 18), (a1[14], 25), (a1[15], 19), (a1[16], 5), (a1[17], 14),
                         (a1[18], 17), (a1[19], 3), (a1[20], 23),
                         (a1[21], 7), (a1[22], 13), (a1[23], 4), (a1[24], 12), (a1[25], 11)]
                    b = [(b1[0], 15), (b1[1], 5), (b1[2], 24), (b1[3], 16), (b1[4], 13), (b1[5], 4), (b1[6], 3),
                         (b1[7], 20), (b1[8], 25), (b1[9], 6), (b1[10], 23),
                         (b1[11], 21), (b1[12], 9), (b1[13], 14), (b1[14], 26), (b1[15], 19), (b1[16], 17), (b1[17], 1),
                         (b1[18], 11), (b1[19], 8), (b1[20], 12),
                         (b1[21], 7), (b1[22], 22), (b1[23], 2), (b1[24], 18), (b1[25], 10)]
                    c = [(c1[0], 9), (c1[1], 11), (c1[2], 6), (c1[3], 14), (c1[4], 13), (c1[5], 8), (c1[6], 22),
                         (c1[7], 26), (c1[8], 16), (c1[9], 2), (c1[10], 5),
                         (c1[11], 25), (c1[12], 23), (c1[13], 21), (c1[14], 17), (c1[15], 24), (c1[16], 20), # the reason this is all derpy is because I copied this from mobile to comuter
                         (c1[17], 18), (c1[18], 3), (c1[19], 19), (c1[20], 15),
                         (c1[21], 1), (c1[22], 10), (c1[23], 12), (c1[24], 4), (c1[25], 7)]
                    break
        final += " "
    print(final)
```

Comment: how is this code being called the first time? Also what is `rotate_a_b_c`? You should be able to produce a MCVE pretty easily here.

Comment: The first letter of the word(a) will go through the encoder. Once it's done that, it will call this function to change the rotor, it does that same path for every letter.    edit: rotate_a_b_c is a function which does the actual rotating, this only tell when to rotate. I will also include the path to get here at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: The function does not return anything and does not change any global variables. It does not remember or change its state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the values of the variables to the function, not the variables themselves. These copies only exist while the function is running, and changing them does not affect the values of the original variables, even though they have the same name.

Try adding

```
global rotate_a, rotate_b, rotate_c
```

at the top of the function, right after the def statement.

Also remove the variables from the def statement and all calls to the function.

```
def rotating(add_amount):
```

Comment: Forgot one thing while I was writing the answer - also remove the variables from the function definition and all function calls. You shouldn't be passing them. By making them global you will be able to access those variable outside the function from inside. I will update my answer.

Comment: I assume you set the initial values of the variables outside the function. The function can then 'see' those variables because it knows they are global. That means the function can change them. When you pass the variables in the function call they get copied, so the function can see the values, but cannot change them outside the function itself.

Comment: I followed what you and others have told me and it has resulted in the desired outcome

Comment: Glad to help. I would appreciate it if you would mark the question as answered. Also, while it's more to learn, I would generally use a class rather than a function as the variables can be contained within the class instead of being declared global. It is definitely worth learning about them if you are interested in Python.

Comment: I am still learning about classes and do not feel ready to start using them though, definitely something I need to know though